# Modify the value of the Tab Bar from a component (react-navigation 6)

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am trying to implement a color customization feature in my React Native app.

I store two values, the main color and the secondary color, with AsyncStorage. Whenever I load a component, I call a function within `ComponentDidMount()` that get the two values and update the State (my State have `mainColor` and `secondaryColor` set to `undefined` by default, and then it gets updated with the new values), and my screen components are rendered with the right colors. This part of the code is working perfectly fine, but I put it here for you to have a little bit of context. (feel free to tell my if you think this is inefficient, or if you know a better way)

My problem was that I also had a header button, with an icon, and I wanted the icon's color to be what's defined by the value `mainColor` stored with AsyncStorage.

My header button is defined inside my App.js file, which manage all the navigation system (I'm using React Navigation 6) :

```
// App.js

import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import Counter from './components/Counter.js';
import AddCounter from './components/AddCounter.js';

// Translation module
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
import { en, fr } from './i18n/supportedLanguages';
i18n.fallbacks = true;
i18n.translations = { en, fr };
i18n.locale = Localization.locale;

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();


// All components managed by TabBar
function TabBar() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={ ({route}) => ({
        tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: "#DDDDDD",
        tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        tabBarShowIcon: true
      })}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="CounterTab"
        component={Counters}
        options= {{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarIcon: () => {
            return (
              <Image
                tintColor="#000000"
                source={require("./assets/add_counter.png")}
                style={styles.icon}
              />
            )
          }
        }} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

// Everything inside the "Counter" tab, which should display the tab bar
function Counters() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Counter"
        component={Counter}
        options={({navigation}) => ({
          title: i18n.t('counters.header_text'),
          headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.add_counter_header}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AddCounter')}>

              <Image
                style={styles.add_counter_button}
                tintColor="#000000"                // <- THE VALUE I WANTED TO BE CUSTOMIZABLE
                source={require("./assets/add_counter.png")}/>

            </TouchableOpacity>
          )
        })} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>

        {/*TabBar display*/}

        <Stack.Screen
          name="TabBar"
          component={TabBar}
          options={{
            headerShown: false
          }} />

        {/*FROM HERE : every screen that shouldn't display the TabBar*/}

        <Stack.Screen
          name="AddCounter"
          component={AddCounter}
          options={{
            title: i18n.t('add_counters.header_text'),
            tabBarStyle: { display: 'none' }
          }} />

      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
  },
  add_counter_header: {
    marginRight: 10
  },
  add_counter_button: {
    height: 26,
    width: 26
  }
});
```

I first thought I should try to get the value of `mainColor`, and then render the app, but I didn't managed to make it work, so I documented myself and found another approach : I load the App with a default color for the header icon (in that case "#000000"), and then I modify it from the Counter component, once the value has been retrieved.

Here is what I did :

```
// Counter.js, the screen that is first rendered when the app launch, and that have an header button

componentDidMount() {

    ( async () => {

      await this._getColors() // this function updates the state with the color values
      this.props.navigation.setOptions({
        headerRight: () => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.add_counter_header}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AddCounter')}>

            <Image
              style={styles.add_counter_button}
              tintColor={this.state.mainColor}  // <- I set the color of the header button here
              source={require("../assets/add_counter.png")}/>

          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      });

    })()
}
```

Again, this is working fine, I have the header button with the color I defined as `mainColor` : [image]

There is one last thing I want to do : it's to customize the color of the TabBar's icon the same way I did with the Header Button. And this is where I have my problem : I have no clue about how to access it from my component, and the only things I found on internet that were responding to a similar problem are outadated. Does somebody have any idea on how I could do ?

I'm sorry if my question isn't formulated right, it's one of the first I'm posting on this website. Feel free to advise my about how to post a good question if necessary. If you see something horrible in my code (something that is coded horribly wrong) don't hesitated to tell me as well, I'm a newbie at React Native.

Thank you for reading this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have several level of navigation so you can reach another navigation level with the `navigation.getParent()` function (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop#getparent)

So in your case it should be :

```
navigation.getParent().setOptions({..})
```

An other way to achieve the behaviour, is to store your colors valuse in a context and then all you navigator could reach that context to apply these colors.

Comment: Thank you, the navigation.getParent() worked ! I don't know how I could have missed that :')
I'll do some researches about the context solution you mentioned, as it seems interesting.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html Here is the documentation